# Link to no framed HTML in jsBin or jsFiddle

Tags: html, javascript, jsfiddle

Is there a way in jsBin or jsFiddle to get a link to the page you created as is, without being embed inside a frame? If not, is there such service (something that would let me quickly create an HTML page and see it live with one click)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** Since Feb-2017(?) it seems this method no longer appears to work unfortunately.

You seem to be able to do this in jsFiddle by first getting the "Share full screen result" URL (from the Share menu) and then view the source of the *full screen result* to get the URL of the iframe used to display the result.

For example, the "full screen result" URL, which still shows a minimal toolbar at the top:

- http://jsfiddle.net/w3dx/sspTY/embedded/result/

From this, you can see the URL of the embedded iframe, which is:

- http://fiddle.jshell.net/w3dx/sspTY/show/light/

Comment: I'd still be nice to have an easier way to do it.

Comment: If you are using Firefox then it's a bit quicker, as you can right-mouse on the iframe and select `This Frame > Show Only This Frame` from the popup menu, and grab the URL from the address bar. Chrome doesn't appear to have a similar feature unfortunately.

Comment: I just noticed on jsBin, if you remove the "/edit" part off of the URL then you get the page alone.

Comment: Seems like jsonp does not work from the "raw" page. http://jsfiddle.net/vm1vr3L0/ works, but not https://jsfiddle.net/vm1vr3L0/embedded/result/ or https://fiddle.jshell.net/vm1vr3L0/show/light/

Comment: This does not work any more.

Comment: As @MattM. pointed out this does not work anymore. The "share" option is not available as such, and the given links "result" and "light" produce a wrapper page with the fiddle content in an iFrame again.